# Jinja2 variable to Javascrip gives object of type Undefined

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

**Background**

After completing a `form` I redirect the user to the `Post page`, with the content he has input on that form. The description input, which is a textarea, has support for markdown text; that markdown text I want to parse before the page loads into html using `showdown`. After submitting the form I save the text in a `Project` object that I pass on the route to the html.

**Route called when form is submitted**

```
''' Route of dynamically generated post. '''
@bp.route('/projects/post/<post_id>')
def post(post_id):
   .....
   return render_template('post.html', title=f'Project {post_id}', project=project)
```

I want to be able to send the `project.background_input' from HTML to javascript to I can use

```
const bg_intro = document.getElementById('project-description-intro')
bg_intro.innerHTML = ` ${converter.makeHtml(project.background_intro)} `
```

**I tried the following:**

1. In my script before the `bundle.js` with the module that converts markdown into html

   ```
   <script type=text/javascript>
     dosth({{ project.background_intro|tojson|safe }}); // ERROR OBJECT OF TYPE UNDEFINED
   </script>
   <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/post-convert/bundle.js') }}"></script>
   ```
2. Create global js variable.

   > Uncaught ReferenceError: background_intro is not defined

   ```
   <script type=text/javascript>var text = {{project.description_intro}};</script> 
   // Uncaught ReferenceError: description_intro is not defined
   <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/post-convert/bundle.js') }}"></script>
   ```

How should I pass my jinja2 variable to javascript?

EDIT:

I captured the output of my `project.description_intro` on my `post` route as following:

```
print(f'Type is {type(project.description_intro)} and the content: {project.description_intro}')
```

With the corresponding output:

```
Type is <class 'str'> and the content: This is a simple text, for testing purposes. This is **bold**. This is a list:
- l1
- l2
```

EDIT2:

**bundle.js**

```
function dosth(text1){
    console.log(text1); // 22:196 Uncaught ReferenceError: dosth is not defined
}
```

**html file**

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  dosth({{ project.description_intro|tojson|safe }}); 
</script>
```

Comment: What are the contents of `project.background_intro` inside the `post` function for that flask endpoint? It would be useful if you could capture the output of `print(project.background_intro)` and edit it into the question.

Comment: @metatoaster did as you said

Comment: There is a real chance background_intro isn't defined, as your edit is not giving project.background_intro rather project.description_intro maybe you mistyped the name in jinja?

Comment: @sergenp I've mistaken `description` to `background`. Check my second edit, after replacing the mistake I still get a `ReferenceError`

Comment: This seems like a javascript issue now, you need to declare your dosth function before trying to access it

Comment: Managed to do it..the mistake was a typo in the name. Too tired, sorry for the wasted time and thanks

Comment: No worries, happens all the time to us all